# What could be a better option to call recursive or better method a JS function which has to retry a request if a value is null

Tags: javascript, node.js

I built a function in my NodeJS backend which has that purpose to retry for 10 times a request if a value on first request is equal to null.
This behavior is need it because there is a worker function which uploads PDF to AWS, so the value I'm retrieving by the new function contains a PDF URL which very often on first request is null.

The goal is to check at first if we have the `pdfUrl` if that is not NULL so return the data.

If the `pdfURL`for some reason is NULL then the function need to retry the request with a timeout of 20s and max 10 retries.

The function I tried is as follow and have several issues:

1. Seems is retrying 10 times either if the pdfUrl is not null instead of retrying only if it is null and only for max retries
2. The function after the 10 times should give back an error exception and not null
3. The function should give up and giving the error only if fails for 10 times

```
async function getIcfDocument(documentId, { log }) {
  log.info('Getting IcfDocument with last revision pdfUrl');
  const MAX_RETRIES = 10;
  const timeout = 20000;

  let data;
  for (let i = 0; i <= MAX_RETRIES; i += 1) {
    try {
      const { icfDocuments } = await request(
        CONSENT_SERVICE_URL,
        getICFDocumentRecipientsQuery,
        {
          documentId,
        }
      );

      if (icfDocuments.nodes[0].revision.pdfUrl) {
        log.info('Success the revision pdfUrl is present');
        data = icfDocuments;
      } else {
        log.debug(
          'Waiting to retrieve the last revision pdfUrl %s ms',
          timeout
        );
        await sleep(timeout);
        log.debug('Retrying times %s', i);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      log.error(
        'Failed to retrieve the data for document %s, Error: %s',
        documentId,
        err.message
      );
      return null;
    }
  }
  return data;
}
```

Will be nice to see a better way to what I have tried as I have some difficulties to make it so.

The request method above is requesting to a GQL query that why was implemented in this way

```
const { icfDocuments } = await request(
            CONSENT_SERVICE_URL,
            getICFDocumentRecipientsQuery,
            {
              documentId,
            }
          );
```

The `icfDocuments` is the resulting OBJ of the query which contains the `urlPdf`and other information. This query has to be retried if that url is null for max 10 times and 20s timeout between requests.

The query is this one as info

```
const getICFDocumentRecipientsQuery = gql`
  query GetICFDocumentRecipients($documentId: ID!) {
    icfDocuments(filter: { ids: [$documentId] }, pagination: { limit: 1 }) {
      nodes {
        id
        recipients {
          id
          email
          phone
          locale
        }
        revision {
          pdfUrl
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: Could you not have the worker notify the parent thread once the file upload is complete? Instead of polling for when it has been uploaded

Comment: I cannot as who did the worker did it without taking in mind events driven so making the worker to do so require a week or so as there are many places to change and there is no time for it as that need to be released, I can only do as above and need to find a good solution in that context. Cannot change the worker unfortunately at this time.

Comment: You want it to stop the loop after it gives the error `Failed to retrieve the data for document`, correct?

Comment: So the function have to fail after 10 times not getting the urlPdf on first request. 
The loop have to stop soon as we have the data right if not continue for max 10 times. More less like this

Answer (score 0):

- Return right away when the data is found without continuing the loop.
- If the pdf url is not found, show log error instead of retry message.

```js
async function getIcfDocument(documentId, { log }) {
  log.info('Getting IcfDocument with last revision pdfUrl');
  const MAX_RETRIES = 10;
  const timeout = 20000;

  for (let i = 0; i <= MAX_RETRIES; i++) {
    try {
      const { icfDocuments } = await request(
        CONSENT_SERVICE_URL,
        getICFDocumentRecipientsQuery,
        {
          documentId,
        }
      );

      if (icfDocuments.nodes[0].revision.pdfUrl) {
        log.info('Success the revision pdfUrl is present');
        return data; // SOLUTION TO #1
      } else {
        if (i == MAX_RETRIES) return log.error('Failed to retrieve pdfUrl after %s tries.', MAX_RETRIES); // SOLUTION TO #2
        log.debug(
          'Waiting to retrieve the last revision pdfUrl %s ms',
          timeout
        );
        await sleep(timeout);
        log.debug('Retrying times %s', i);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      log.error(
        'Failed to retrieve the data for document %s, Error: %s',
        documentId,
        err.message
      );
      break;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```